# Extension Select methods for Entity Framework

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework-4.1

I have many similar calls to database and they work fine

```
Using ta As New QT_SSTEntities
 Return ta.Product.
   Select(Function(c) New RadComboBoxData() With {.Text = c.FieldName1, .Value = c.FieldName1}).
   ToArray()
End Using

Using ta As New QT_SSTEntities
 Return ta.City.
   Select(Function(c) New RadComboBoxData() With {.Text = c.CityName, .Value = c.CityName}).
   ToArray()
End Using

Using ta As New QT_SSTEntities
 Return ta.OtherProduct.
   Select(Function(c) New RadComboBoxData() With {.Text = c.FieldName3, .Value = c.FieldName3}).
   ToArray()
End Using
```

They produce sql code like that:

```
  SELECT FieldName1 FROM Product
```

I want to extact

```
Select(Function(c) New RadComboBoxData() With {.Text = c.SomeField, .Value = c.SomeField}).ToArray()
```

into another method (smth. like that but it doesn't work).

```
<Extension()>
Public Function ToRadComboBoxData(Of TSource, TItem)(ByVal source As IQueryable(Of TSource), selector As Expression(of Func(Of TSource, TItem))) As RadComboBoxData()
   Dim r = (From row In source Select selector(row)).ToArray() 'Build tree from expression. How???
   Return (From v In r
     Let rv = If(v Is Nothing, Nothing, v.ToString())
     Select New RadComboBoxData() With {.Text = rv, .Value = rv}).ToArray()

End Function
```

and make calls in the following way:

```
Using ta As New QT_SSTEntities
  Return ta.Product.ToRadComboBoxData(Function(c) c.FieldName1)
End Using

Using ta As New QT_SSTEntities
  Return ta.City.ToRadComboBoxData(Function(c) c.CityName)
End Using

Using ta As New QT_SSTEntities
  Return ta.OtherProduct.ToRadComboBoxData(Function(c) c.FieldName3)
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

When enumerated, an `IQueryable` query is translated to SQL. But not everything can be translated to SQL: for instance creating a `RadComboBoxData` makes no sense for a SQL database. So this code needs to be executed in memory, on the result of the query. Just replace `IQueryable` with `IEnumerable`, and it should give you the expected result:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function ToRadComboBoxData(Of TSource, TItem)(ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of TSource), selector As Func(Of TSource, TItem)) As RadComboBoxData()
  Return (From row In source
    Let v = selector(row)
    Let rv = If(v Is Nothing, Nothing, v.ToString())
    Select New RadComboBoxData() With {.Text = rv, .Value = rv}).ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, it works now, thanks! The last question - in this case EF generates sql to collect all fields from specified table. It would be great to select only single field passed as Func<>. So we need to pass an expression, generate   Select FieldName ... sql and after that create RadComboBoxData from IEnumerable. How can we do that?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question... is this what you want? `Return ta.Product.Select(Function(p) => p.FieldName).ToRadComboBoxData(Function(c) c)`

Comment: I've updated my question. Please see **Edit 2** section of the topic

Comment: Be aware that if you use this strategy, the query will be materialized before this method is called. So if you're only interested in the `rv` value, but the Source object has a lot of other data on it, you could be getting a lot more information from the database than you really need. And this strategy definitely shouldn't be extended to `Where` clauses.

Comment: ... however, as I look at this more, the ToRadComboBoxData method should not be used on unmaterialized queries: it belongs in the front-end. So +1.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior >you could be getting a lot more information from the database than you really need
This is what I'm trying to avoid and create such extension which will load only `rv` value from the database

Comment: @Cheburek: Then the appropriate thing to do is to create a DTO that has only the information you need, and create a data-layer repository that gets items of that DTO type out of your data store. Then use the extension method on the front-end to convert those DTOs into a combo box. Don't make your combo box pull stuff straight from the database.